# Calculated Measure using dimension

Tags: ssas, olap, mdx, cube, cubes

I am trying to build a calculated measure in SSAS that incorporates a dimension parameter. I have two facts: Members & Orders and one Dimension: Date. Members represents all the unique members on my site. Orders are related to members by a fact key representing a unique user. Orders also contains a key representing the vendor for an order. Orders contains a key to the date dimension.

FactMember
 - MemberFactKey
 - MemberId
FactOrder
 - FactOrderKey
 - OrderId
 - FactMemberKey
 - DimVendorKey
 - DimDateKey
DimDate
 - DimDateKey
 - FYYear

The calculated measure I am trying to build is the number of unique vendors a member has ordered from. The value of the calculation must of course change based on the date dimension.

Comment: Do you mean member as in 'of a club' or member as in 'of a dimension'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't the DISTINCTCOUNT function be the one to use here? Creating a distinct count of Vendors could then be used in this query and elsewhere.

```
WITH MEMBER [Test]
AS
DISTINCTCOUNT([Vendor].[Vendor].[Vendor])
```

I will say in advance that this may well be slow (Depending on data volume/distribution), so if this query will be a popular/big part of the design it may be worth considering a restructure.

Answer (score 0):

I am confused, it would make more sense to make Members and Orders both separate dimensions and then reference them from a FACT table, say Fact.Sales. This would eliminate the need to even build a calculated member if you keyed your Members dimension on some sort of member_key.

Comment: Redesigning my entire fact & dimension structure just to make a single calculated member easier to build isn't really an option.

Comment: Well this calculation seems like something that would be quite common which is why I concluded maybe the structure of the cube itself needed to be re-evaluated. I wasn't aware that it wasn't in the realm of possibility in your situation.